# Mongoose object refuses to save with .save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To give some context: I have a Java client application that communicates high scores to a Node.js backend via sockets.  All of those aspects are working correctly.  The issue is that, when I run the object.save() method, it doesn't save the object in the db.  It also doesn't throw any errors, and doesn't even console.log() like it's meant to.

Here is my code.

```
socket.on('setScore',function(data){
    var workingScore = new Score(data);
    console.log("WorkingScore:");
    console.log(workingScore);

    workingScore.save(function(err){
      console.log("MADE IT THIS FAR");
      if(err)
        {console.log(err)}
      else
        {console.log("Saved!")}
    })
});
```

None of the three console.log() handlers fire within the workingScore.save() callback.

When I create the server, I connect to my mongodb database, and this appears to work, as the mongod console shows a new connection when the server is started.  The code for that is:

mongoose.createConnection('localhost','LeaderboardDB');

When I open mongo from terminal and do `use LeaderboardDB` then `show collections` nothing comes up.

Comment: Because the connection string is wrong. `mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/LeaderboardDB")`. The second option is NOT for the database name, but is an `options` object for connection settings. Your data is in the "default" `test` namespace.

Comment: @NeilLunn Even after I changed the createConnection string to the one you've specified, it still doesn't work and none of the 3 console.log() statements fire.

Comment: @NeilLunn I can also verify that the Node.js server is connecting to the db by viewing the `mongod` console, which shows a new connection being created when I launch the server.

Comment: Then you likely mean `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/LeaderboardDB‌​",{ useMongoClient: true }).then( conn => /* rest of code after connected /* )` Read [connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) in the documentation. You would have likely been given a warning message attempting `.connect()` before, but you actually need to pay attention to the full text of the warning message. `createConnection()` does not actually "connect" unless you have other code explicitly doing that.

Comment: This solved it.  I added the bit to create the score schema within the .then().  If you post this solution as an answer, I'll accept it.  Also, for the record, using mongoose.connect('localhost',LeaderboardDB').then(...etc) does actually work.